# Gitlab pipeline `WARNING:root:No ancestry detected`

Tags: gitlab, pipeline, scanning

This is a general question.
On our team we are using Anchore to scan Docker images we create. During the scan stage one or our projects is receiving the error `WARNING:root:No ancestry detected`. We do have some custom scripts to kick off certain stages so I know this is very vague but just curious if anyone has encountered this error before and can shed some light on it. I cannot find almost anything on this error using the googles.

I am not familiar with how our Anchore tool is set up so cannot really help there. Am willing to answer any questions though that I can.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was for a tomcat-openjdk project. Anchore said it's an issue with how they handle JARs with no virtualpaths. A fix will be released in 4.7.